# How to display all rows linked to a table, then fill some of those rows with data from another table (conditiionally)

Tags: mysql, sql

As title says, I have 3 tables, I am attempting to display the entirety of a single column from table 1 and then multiple columns from table 3 where a condition is met in table 2, any ideas?

Table 1
[image]

Table 2 [image]

Table 3 [image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: tables added, desired results are: all of badge column and if badge has been purchased: first name last name and email of all players who have purchased badge

Answer (score 0):

It's better to post sql script to create and add data to tables so we can run it. Maybe something like this.

```
select t2.firstName
, t2.lastName
, t2.email 
from Table2 t2
inner join Table3 t3 on t2.username = t3.username
inner join Table1 t1 on t3.badgeID = t1.badgeID
```